# Dynamic destination with spring cloud stream - Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-function

I'm developing a router (events proxy) application with spring cloud stream over Kafka, in the functional paradigm. the application consumes from constant input topic, maps and filters the message and then should send it to some topic according to some input fields (only single message at a time, not multiple results).

Is the best way to do it by setting the `spring.cloud.stream.sendto.destination` header for the output message?
and if so, how should I set the bindings for the producer?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [StreamBridge](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.2.1/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_sending_arbitrary_data_to_an_output_e_g_foreign_event_driven_sources)
With regard to the binding configuration. . .
If they are truly dynamic where you don't know the name of the destination (e.g., may come with message header), there is nothing you can do with regard to configuring it.
If they are semi dynamic where you do know the name(s) and it's a limited set of names, then you can configure then as any other binding.
For example, let's say you are sending to destination `foo`, than you can use `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.foo.....`